# Deriving a workflow activity from native activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a base class called "BaseActivity" Derived from a NativeActivity. I want to have all my common behavior in the base class and make use of them in the dervied classes. Let's say i have common in / out arguments in base class. My derived classes have its own in / out arguments. My question is, how can i pass an out argument from my dervied class to the base class, so that the base class out argument will pass the message back to the client?

BASEACTIVITY CLASS

public class BaseActivity : NativeActivity
    {
        #region "Public Argument List"
        // Define an activity input / output  argument of type string
        public InArgument FirstArgument{ get; set; }
        public InArgument SecondArgument{ get; set; }
        public OutArgument Result { get; set; }

public virtual NativeActivityContext PushContext(NativeActivityContext context, Dictionary DictBase)
        {
            return context;
        }

protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);

```
    }
```

protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {

```
        // Read context variables to local string variables.

        string firstVal= context.GetValue(this.FirstArgument);
        string secondVal= context.GetValue(this.SecondArgument);

        string OutputResult = context.GetValue(this.Result);


        Dictionary<string, object> contextdictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        contextdictionary.Add("first", firstVal);
        contextdictionary.Add("second", secondVal);

        contextdictionary.Add("output", OutputResult);




         NativeActivityContext finalContext = PushContext(context, contextdictionary);




    }
```

}

DERIVED CLASS

public  class Child: BaseActivity
    {
        public InArgument XsltPath { get; set; }
        public OutArgument OutValue{ get; set; }

public override NativeActivityContext PushContext(NativeActivityContext context, Dictionary DictBase)
        {
            // Some String manipulation and then pass it.
                OutValue.Set(context, outputStringBuilder.ToString());

```
        }



        return context;
    }
```

}

The question is how can i pass the OutValue to the base activity out argument.  The value in the child activity is correct but when i invoke a worklfow it returns an empty string. pl. help me.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: could you update your post to have better formatting ? Because your code is not correctly formatted

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just forward your derived argument to the base class ?

```
public InArgument<string> XsltPath 
{ 
    get { return base.FirstArgument; } 
    set { base.FirstArgument = value; }
}
public OutArgument<string> OutValue
{
    get { return base.SecondArgument; } 
    set { base.SecondArgument = value; }
}
```